# Docker: Run echo command don't work on my window container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker image with the following dockerfile code:

```
FROM scratch 
RUN echo "Hello World - Dockerfile"
```

And I build my image in a powershell prompt like this:

```
docker build -t imagename .
```

Here is what I do when I build my image :

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  194.5MB
Step 1/2 : FROM scratch
 --->
Step 2/2 : RUN echo "Hello World - Dockerfile"
 ---> Running in 42d5e5add10e
invalid reference format
```

I want to run my image with a windows container. 
What is missing to make it work?
Thanks

Comment: don't think scratch base image gonna help here. try FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image doesn't have a command called `echo`.

A `FROM scratch` image contains absolutely nothing at all.  No shells, no libraries, no system programs, nothing.  The two most common uses for it are to build a base image from a tar file or to build an extremely minimal image from a statically-linked binary; both are somewhat advanced uses.

Usually you'll want to start from an image that contains a more typical set of operating system tools.  On a Linux base (where I'm more familiar) `ubuntu` and `debian` are common, `alpine` as well (though it has some occasionally compatibility issues).  @gp. suggests `FROM microsoft/windowsservercore` in a comment and that's probably a good place to start for a Windows container.